# Excel Copy Values and not Formulars and formating as Standard

Tags: microsoft-excel, default-settings

99% of the time i do NOT want to copy formatting and formulas, only the numbers.

I know i can right click and select past only numbers - but is there a way to make this default for Ctrl+c and ctrl+V

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a shortcut key, you can use Ctrl+Alt+V to paste and select it in the pop-up dialog box.
[image]

Comment: Yes know how to do this, but I do not want  4 extra steps 99% of the time, so i wanted the DEFAULT copy paste to be values only :)...